# How can I make ggplotly show hover tooltips for a geom_rect series?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggplotly

I am trying to create an interactive visualisation of an individual's salary growth across multiple employers. I am using a geom_rect series to show pay periods and salary information. When I apply the ggplotly function, hover tooltips are not showing by default, and I cannot find a way to enable them.

What can I do to enable tooltips over the geom_rect?

data:

```
df <- data.frame(
"From" = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2026-01-01"), by = 14),
"To" = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2026-01-01"), by = 14)+13,
"Employer" = c(rep("Current employer",130),rep("Future employer",131)),
"Salary" = seq(50000,250000,length.out = 261)
)
```

vis:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
ggplotly(
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = From, xmax = To,
                ymin = Employer, ymax = Employer,
                colour = Employer,
                size = Salary))
)
```

Output (no hover text):
[image: Output]

Please note I have also asked a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65269966/how-do-i-get-ggplotly-rangeslider-to-set-a-sensible-initial-range-with-a-date-ax) on the application of a rangeslider to this problem.

Comment: This is a different issue. That issue was about disabling working tooltips on geom_rect. My issue is about enabling missing tooltips on geom_rect.

Comment: Ok, i removed the link comment

Answer (score 1):

In this case `geom_rect()` is an special aesthetic element compared to classic `plotly` elements like dots or bars. That is why even enabling `tooltip` you can not get them. You would need to create the labels such that they can be recognized as known elements for `ggplotly()` like those mentioned initially. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
#Code
ggplotly(ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = From, xmax = To,
                  ymin = Employer, ymax = Employer,
                  colour = Employer,
                  size = Salary))+
  geom_line(aes(x = From,
                y = Employer,
                group = 1,
                text = paste("Date: ",
                             From, "<br>Salary: ", Salary)),
            color='transparent') + 
  geom_point(aes(x = From,
                 y = Employer,
                 text = paste("Date: ", From, "<br>Salary: ",
                              Salary)),
             color='transparent'),tooltip = 'text')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This is a useful work-around. However, I believe tooltips can be applied to geom_rect elements. For example: However, I I know that tooltips can be applied to geom_rect in some circumstances. For example: 
ggplotly(
ggplot()+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1, xmax = 2, ymin = 1, ymax = 2, text = paste("here is some text"))),
tooltip = 'text'
)

Comment: @Luke23 Yeah sometimes can work, but as stated in the web page of plotly some aesthetics elements from ggplot2 do not work properly in plotly, that is why you can hack the plots using elements like dots, lines or bars. In any sense I hope this code helped you with your issue, and if any is not clear do not hesitate to mention it, glad to help!